# Call emacsclient from a program called by Emacs

Tags: auctex, emacsclient, pdf-tools

I've run into a problem viewing pdf documentation files with AucTex. I use `pdf-tools` to view PDF files from within Emacs, and I've set `emacsclient -n` as my default pdf-viewer (via xdg-mime on Debian Linux). This works fine in most circumstances, but it breaks the `(Tex-documentation-texdoc ...)` function of Auctex (`C-c ?`).

I've narrowed the problem down to a single line of code. When I try to view the documentation for the `listings` package, `TeX-documentation-texdoc` turns this into the following sexp:

```
(shell-command-to-string "texdoc --view  listings")
```

`texdoc` in turn calls `emacsclient` to actually open the file (based on how I've configured my desktop via xdg). However, at this point, the Emacs hangs and I need to quit (`C-g`) to get control back. After that, no new pdf is opened. The same thing happens if I try to call emacsclient directly:

```
(shell-command-to-string "emacsclient -n tmp.pdf")
```

Both commands work at the command line (i.e., `emacsclient -n tmp.pdf` and `texdoc --view listings`.

My question is, in an instance like this, how do I call emacsclient from within Emacs? (and I know I could just open the pdf file with `find-file`; that's not an option here as I need to call an external process (texdoc) to find the file, and that process then invokes emacsclient).

Comment: Why not just use `texdoc -M --list listings` to find the file, and then use `find-file`?

Comment: @suvayu Just convenience. Another alternative is switching to a terminal to call `texdoc --view` and then switching back to Emacs when it opens the file. But I think there should be a way to do this in a single step from Emacs?

Comment: Can `(async-shell-command "emacsclient -n tmp.pdf")` solve the problem?

Comment: @Name interesting - `(async-shell-command "emacsclient -n tmp.pdf")` works, but not `(async-shell-command "texdoc --view listings")` doesn't. So that's a useful clue.

Comment: I don't have access to a linux machine to test. What error or message (async-shell-command "texdoc --view listings") produces?

Comment: Might be similar to [#25234](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25234 "call-process vs. start-process and xdg-open"), i.e., `texdoc -M --list listings` exits too early?

Comment: @npostavs that does sounds very similar, thanks

Comment: @Name no error, it just reports: `texdoc --view listings: finished.`, without actually displaying the doc in question. An empty `*Async Shell Command*` buffer opens up, but with no contents.

Comment: Does `C-u C-c ?` work?  It first shows the list of docs related to the package, then opens the viewer with `(call-process "texdoc" nil 0 nil "--just-view" doc)`.

Comment: @giordano yes it does!

Comment: Good.  I needed to use `shell-command-to-string` in order to show to users possible error messages in case no documentation is found (as explained in comments).  The problem of `call-process` is that it doesn't tell anything to Emacs about the exit status of the program when `destination` is 0.  I couldn't find a solution for this case, that's why I resorted to `shell-command-to-string`.

Comment: @giordano 1. do you want to submit using `call-process` instead of `shell-command` as an answer to this question? 2. Is this something that can be incorporated into Auctex, or should I write my own function for calling tex-doc to use locally?

Comment: @giordano sounds like you should use `start-process` and with a [sentinel](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html) to catch error exit statuses.

Comment: @Tyler Stefan answered the question (the trick is to call an asynchronous process).  Regarding 2) I'd accept in AUCTeX a simple solution that doesn't break handling of the case of a doc not available (it's annoying for the user to not see the documentation being opened without any explanation).  As I said in the comment to Stefan's answer, using a sentinel looks to me a bit too complicated for a non-fundamental feature (or you can persuade me this is a really good idea to use a sentinel even here ;-).

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to run `texdoc` within an asynchronous process.

The best way to do that is probably to use `start-file-process` instead of `shell-command-to-string` (which is a handy function for quick&dirty code when it's more expedient to write a little shell script than the corresponding Elisp code, but is otherwise better avoided in my experience).

But it will require substantial changes to the surrounding code, since `start-file-process` does not return the process's output directly, instead it lets you indicate in which buffer to place the output and then you have to use `set-process-sentinel` to a callback function that fetches the output from that buffer and does "whatever needs to be done with it" when the command finishes.

Comment: In the specific case of running `texdoc` in AUCTeX I find the use of a sentinel a bit of an overkill, since this isn't a fundamental feature (like it is the opening of the viewer for the output document, in which case we do use the sentinel).

Comment: I have no idea why the "-to-string" function was used, so I don't know what is done with the command's output.  If this output is needed (as suggested by the use of `...-to-string`), then an async solution will either need a process-filter or a proces-sentinel.  If not, then the code can maybe use something like `(shell-command "texdoc --view  listings &")`.

Comment: It's explained in the comments to `TeX-documentation-texdoc`: the `...-to-string` variant is used to show to users possible error messages (for example when no documentation is found).  In addition, `texdoc nonexistingpackage` returns 0, but the sentinel may be used to parse the output.

Comment: Then a sentinel seems to be the best option.

Comment: I can't find an invocation of `start-file-process` that actually works here. `(start-file-process "texdoc" "*texdoc*" "texdoc" "--view"  "listings")` creates the buffer `*texdoc*`, to which is inserted "Process texdoc finished", and the pdf never opens. The same thing happens when I set the xdg-mime pdf viewer to evince as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to feed back a request to Emacs, without waiting for an answer, then you can run `emacsclient` in the background. Under Unix-style OSes (Linux, macOS, Cygwin, …):

```
emacsclient … &
```

Under native Windows:

```
start emacsclient …
```

Comment: Sure, but in this particular case I need to call a program (texdoc) that then calls (emacsclient). The additional level of redirection is causing problems.

Comment: @Tyler `texdoc` is asynchronous (i.e. you aren't waiting for it to complete), isn't it? So you could apply the same principle: run `texdoc … &` as the shell command.

Comment: We tried that up in the comments under my question; it works when calling `emacsclient` directly, but not when calling `texdoc`.