# Running a program from elisp that runs `emacsclient` set on `$EDITOR`

Tags: emacsclient, environment

I'm automating some work tasks, and many of them consist of calling `kubectl edit` on different objects.

`kubectl edit` basically opens your `$EDITOR` which I have configured to be `emacsclient`.

My question is, how can I, from `elisp` run a command like `kubectl edit` that consists on a blocking call (waits for completion) to `emacsclient`, have all the edits I need done with `emacsclient` and then continue the execution of the `elisp` function?

Or maybe, instead of using `$EDITOR` to emacsclient can I set `$EDITOR` to something like: "the current running Emacs instance"?

I've found [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29508/call-emacsclient-from-a-program-called-by-emacs) that seem to be similar to my problem. But I wanted to know if there's a way for Emacs to understand that a command is calling `$EDITOR` and use the current instance, instead of doing it through `emacsclient`.

Comment: I think that Magit does something similar, with git. I think it start the external command in async mode, let it run `emacsclient`. It triggers Emacs to open a commit window. When the user is done, `emacsclient` is notified so that the external process can exit. (Reservation: I'm not an expert on Magit, so my understanding might be oversimplified, or even plain wrong.)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `with-editor` library (which is what @Lindydancer is alluding to in the comment about Magit).

https://elpa.nongnu.org/nongnu/with-editor.html

> It provides the commands `with-editor-async-shell-command` and
> `with-editor-shell-command`, which are intended as replacements
> for `async-shell-command` and `shell-command`.  They automatically
> export `$EDITOR` making sure the executed command uses the current
> Emacs instance as "the editor".

Example:

```el
(defun my-crontab-edit ()
  "Edit crontab."
  (interactive)
  (require 'with-editor)
  (with-editor-async-shell-command "crontab -e"))
```